# Log Shipping Agent Jobs Not Running

Tags: sql-server

I have several log shipping jobs that I have configured to run every 15 minutes.  I am clicking on the job history to find that they have not run.  I can manually run them fine.  There are no errors.  Why would these jobs not be running on their own?

(SQL 2014 shipping to SQL 2016)

Edit: Additional Confusing Information

To add to my confusion, I right clicked on the primary server and clicked on Reports > Transaction Log Shipping Reports.  The image below shows an issue in the very first row with the AppMng_Service_DB... database.  I checked the folder where this database is supposed to back up it's transactions to and the files are there (as recent as 15 minutes ago).  Why would this report show Time Since Last Backup 1230min?  Is this an alert created from a potentially old deleted log shipping job?

[image]

Comment: Are you only relying on the job history in the UI to determine they have not run? Is it possible you have some combination of (a) a lot of jobs and (b) a very restrictive agent log retention policy?

Comment: Check to make sure there are schedules attached to each job and that the schedules are enabled. You can find this by right-clicking the job -> Properties -> Schedules.

Comment: If they are scheduled and enabled, did the schedule expire?   What does Next Run Date show for them in Job Activity Monitor?

Comment: Weird.  I created all of the jobs the same way.  They all run every 15 minutes.  On some jobs, I click view history and there are logs showing the last couple of times the job was run.  On others, I click and there are no logs but if I click properties for that job there is an entry for the Last executed with a time stamp showing the job was executed.